# Xcode Version 9.1 (9B55) upload Archive failed - iOS 11.1 - Apps must be built with the public (GM) version

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ios11, xcode9.1

Today Apple just released `Xcode 9.1 (build 9B55)` and provided also the new update of `iOS 11.1`.

I just tried to upload my new archive, but unfortunately it fails with the following error message:

> ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds."

[image: Xcode error - upload within new 9.1 version]

It worked with the previous version `Xcode 9.01`. I'm wondering, if there is something new to consider? Just to be clear, I'm not using any beta software - this is the final build downloaded/updated from the AppStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated your macOS to 10.13.1 as well? All software should be up to date.

If all is updated, I'd just give it a couple hours and re-build then – maybe Apple didn't update the requirements in iTunes Connect yet. Just a guess.

Comment: Yes, I updated macOS to 10.13.1 - good hint regarding the iTunes Connect update on Apple side .. let's wait

Comment: Same issue here. Just installed the security update. Now I can't submit to iTunes Connect.  Gotta wait until Apple recognizes their own security update as the most recent version.  *sigh*

Comment: Sometimes a little bit of patience is good :) I tried it again and now it works. @Durandal - FYI